# Placing Datepicker,Table and HyperLinks inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a design where i need to place a datepicker to the left most place of page,then put a table with width remaining from the datepicker to the end of the webpage and height of `500px`.Below to the datepicker and ,left of the table space i need to place Hyperlinks.But i am not able to do it..either table goes down or hyperlinks..

Here i am attaching a rough pic that denotes how i require..
[image: Div design]

Here is my code in html..

```
//Datepicker 

<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;margin-left:5px;margin-top:20px;width:166px"></div>

//Hyperlink

<div style="float:left;margin-left:5px; margin-top:5px; width:166px">

    <label name="roomOperation" id="roomOperation" style="font-style:normal;margin-left:20px; 
                       font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;">Room Operation</label>

    </br>
    </br>

    <a href="#" onclick="addTab('google','http://www.google.com')">Check in List</a> 

    </br>
    </br>

    <a href="#" onclick="addTab('google','http://www.google.com')">Check out List</a> 


</div>

//dynamic tab table

<div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:5px;width:1024px;height:768px;">
    <div title="Home" style="padding:20px">
        <p>Click the above button to add a new tab panel.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me ..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: @AliGajani I am sorry but i dont know how to create that ,,Please refer my Pic in the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created Sample code here take a look [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3WMX/1/)

You can use Datepicker in place of select box.

```
<div style="width:20%;height:300px;float:left;border:1px solid">
    <select style="width:100%">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a> 
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a> 
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a>
    <a href="#" style="display:block">link</a> 
</div>
<div style="width:79%;height:300px;float:left;border:1px solid">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```